# Which parameter can determine the object size in RADOS of Ceph

Tags: object, size, ceph

When storing files, Ceph will cut files into several objects while most of which have the same size except the last one(the file size may not be a multiple of the object size).

I know from the official website of Ceph that the object size is not fixed but can be determined by a certain parameter, so which is the parameter deciding the object size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ceph file system is built on top of the RADOS object storage system. That is, the bytes in a file are stored in one or more objects. The way that bytes in a file map onto objects is referred to as the striping strategy. For example, in a striping strategy with fixed 1 MB objects, the bytes in a file at offsets `[0, 2**20)` may be stored in object.0, and the second megabyte `[2**20, 2**21)` stored in object.1, and so on. There are other ways to map the linear byte stream onto objects. There is more information here:

http://ceph.com/docs/master/cephfs/file-layouts/

and you can change the striping strategy programmatically when you are using libcephfs:

https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/master/src/include/cephfs/libcephfs.h#L738

Notice here that this mapping implies a fixed object size. However, RADOS itself imposes no restrictions on object size (except a configurable maximum size). So if you are using the RADOS object API to store data, there isn't a fixed size.

Comment: But here is another question, that is, how to manipulate the parameter to change the default object size. For example, how to operate on the parameter if I want to change the default object size to 2MB?

Comment: @user4635389 you can change the striping strategy of a file which will indirectly limit the size of an object using `ceph_open_layout`. However, if you are working directly with objects there is no default size.